# How to import local xml file into my vue component

Tags: xml, vue.js

I'm trying to import sitemap.xml into my vue component.

But when i run the following code, i get error 404 not found.

```
import axios from "axios";

var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      paths: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("static/sitemap.xml")
      .then((response) => {
        var self = this;
        parseString(response.data, function(err, result) {
          self.paths = result;
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      .then(console.log(this.paths));
  },
};
```

I also tried importing it as following

```
import sitemap from "../static/sitemap.xml"
```

But this gives the error "Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

I was wondering if someone can help me out :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up since things. The axios call is meant to make a http request to your server. Is the XML file available on the server at the specified path? The import is js code to import js modules/objects, not to import/open files.

Comment: I fixed it by moving the file to my public directory.